# Number of teams

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinations

There are $8$ women and $7$ men, from which we must create a team of $4$ women and $3$ men. Two men doesn't like each other, so they don't want to be in one team.

I tried number of teams (without the specific two deviant men): $\binom{8}{4}\times \binom{7}{3}$ but it's not correct.

The given solution is: $\binom{6}{2}\binom{8}{4}\cdot2+\binom{5}{3}\cdot \binom{8}{4}=2800$, which is more than $\binom{8}{4}\times \binom{7}{3}=2450$.

Comment: Why do you say it's not correct?

Comment: I have a given solution (specific with numbers), and it's not this. Is it correct anyway?

Comment: What did that given solution say?

Comment: With variable $n,k$ we cannot have a numerical expression. That would imply that we'd have the same number of combinations with $5$ women and $3$ men that we'd have with $500$ women and $300$ men, which clearly isn't the case.

Comment: That's not true @Tiwa

Comment: The exact problem is: there is 8 women, 7 men, the team: 4 women and 3 men. Two men doesn't like each other, so they don't want to be in one team. The solution is: $\binom{6}{2}\binom{8}{4}cdot2+\binom{5}{3}\cdot\binom{8}{4}=2800$, which is more than $\binom{8}{4}\binom{7}{3}=2450$.

Comment: It would have been far better to have posted the same in your question.

Comment: @amWhy Why isn't that true?

Comment: @Zsembes That is much different from what you originally asked. You might want to edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: I think you and I were trying to say the same thing, but addressing different facets.  Indeed, the number of women, n, cannot equal the number of all possible teams.  I was looking at just the right side of the askers question, for which it does matter whether the number of women is 5, men, 3, or 500, 300 respectively.

Comment: @Tina yes, first I wanted to solve the problem without the 2 mens, who doesn't like each other. But my solution is less, then the specific one, and I think, it has to be more.

Comment: @Zsembes Are you sure the answer is $2800$?

Answer (score 4):

To solve this, we find the number of ways of choosing the women, and multiply that by the number of ways of choosing the men.

So we begin by counting the $4$ women out of the $8$ in total. That's $\binom 84$ ways to count the women.

Call the feuding men $A$ and $B$. Then one and only one of the following can be true for any team configuration:

(i) A is on the team

(ii) B is on the team

(iii) Neither are on the team.

Case (i): We choose $2$ of the remaining $5$ (we guarantee A and exclude B).

Case (ii): We choose $2$ of the remaining $5$ (we guarantee B and exclude A).

Case (iii): We choose $3$ of the remaining $5$ (we exclude A and B).

This yields $\binom52 + \binom52 + \binom53$ combinations for the men.

Now we multiply them together to acquire $$\binom 84 \Bigg(\binom52 + \binom52 + \binom53 \Bigg) = 2100$$

---

**Alternative method.** *Sans restriction*, we can choose $3$ men from the $7$ we have in $\binom 73$ ways. Now we need to subtract the cases that we shouldn't have counted. The cases that we shouldn't have counted were those in which the who feuding men were together. If they're together, then there are $\binom{7-2}{1} = 5$ ways to choose the last man, which means $5$ of our counts should be excluded. And so we have $$\binom 84 \Bigg(\binom73 - 5 \Bigg) = 2100$$

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand *why* the book answer is incorrect.

The first term for counting men *overcounts*. $\dbinom62$ leaves out $A$, say, from contention, but $B$ still remains in contention !

The correct way for the 1st term is to remove *both* from contention, and choose one of the two, thus

$\dbinom84\left[\dbinom52\dbinom21 + \dbinom53\right] = 2100$

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

1) No matter what, the number of women on the team can be computed as $\binom{8}{4}$

2) $\binom{8}{4}\times \binom{7}{3} = 2450$. $\binom{8}{4}\times \binom{6}{2}+\binom{8}{4}\times \binom{5}{3} = 1750$, not $2800$.

3) Count the teams containing neither of the special men. Then add the count of teams containing the first special man. Next add the count of teams containing the second special man. Finally, multiply that result by the (independent) count  of the women. Once you see how to break up the count, the numbers work out easily.